# How do I mount attached drive /home or something similar on VPS

Tags: permissions, mount, home, chown, vps

I obtained a VPS and they attached a 16TB HDD...
They gave me a guide to mount the HDD to folder `/hdd`.

My issue is that the program I am installing on a sudo user has a lot of small apps that get installed to `/home/user`.
The small apps also have several other users that need to be created as time goes by and they all need access to this `/hdd` mount.
Also, any of the small apps & users only see the main SSD storage and not the `/hdd` mount.
I need to use the the 16TB HDD for everything though, so it needs to be seen.

I was able to `chown` the `/hdd` with the sudo user, but I don't know how to make it accessible to all users.
Can this be done with making my own group and `chown` the `/hdd` that way?
What about the files and folders after `/hdd` though, the permissions will be changed if anything is edited right?

I edited the title of this to mention /home.
I was thinking that maybe if I could `mount` the HDD to `/home` instead of `/hdd` it would fix all my problems. If I did that, would it be as easy as mounting to `/hdd`?

However, if I do find a way to mount as `/home` or replace current `/home`. Would I still get permission issues?

If someone has any solution, I would appreciate it. Even if it's not the one I thought of.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be: create `/hdd/home/` and `/hdd/appdata`. for your app-user you define `/hdd/home/appuser` as its homedir (see `man useradd` or `man usermod`) and you can generate a new group and `chgrp` `/hdd/appdata/` to that group.
All new users, that need access to `/hdd/appdata` need to be added to that group as well as the app-user. Make sure, all members of that group have write permission on `/hdd/appdata`: `chmod 770 /hdd/appdata` (or even set the group "restrict deletion" bit: `chmod 2770 /hdd/appdata` (`man chmod`))